# How do I call a method in the controller from the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models called Event and Ticket.
An event has many tickets and a ticket belongs to an event.
In the event show view I want a link or button called 'Generate Tickets' which when clicked should call the generate_tickets method in the controller, which should generate the tickets and link the array of tickets to the event.

Also I would prefer if after generating the method it stayed on the same page and notified that the tickets had been generated, rather than being redirected.

I researched this and saw that I needed a helper method in the event controller which i created and in the show view I have this method..

```
<%= link_to "Generate Tickets", :controller => :events, :method => :generate_tickets %>
```

but this doesn't appear to be calling the method.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your `link_to` like below

```
<%= link_to "Generate Tickets", :controller => :events, :action => :generate_tickets %>
```

You should call the ***controller method*** with `:action` not `:method`.
The `:method` is used to specify the ***HTTP verb*** (i.e, `POST, GET, PUT, PATCH`).

More Info [***Here***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to).

Also I would prefer doing this by defining a `route` and giving it as a path for `link_to`

```
#routes.rb
  get "generate_tickets", to: 'events#generate_tickets', as:'generate_tickets'
```

And then the `link_to` will become

```
<%= link_to "Generate Tickets", generate_tickets_path %>
```